# value error in python statsmodels.tsa.seasonal

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, time-series, decomposition

I have this dataframe with date time indices:

```
ts_log:
```

```
date    price_per_unit
2013-04-04  12.762369
2013-04-05  12.777120
2013-04-06  12.773146
2013-04-07  12.780774
2013-04-08  12.786835
```

I have this piece of code for `decomposition`

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(ts_log)

trend = decomposition.trend
seasonal = decomposition.seasonal
residual = decomposition.resid
```

but in the line     `decomposition = seasonal_decompose(ts_log)`
i got this error :

```
ValueError: You must specify a freq or x must be a pandas object with a timeseries index
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After some searching i found [here][1] that, i have to add `values` to `ts_log.price`

`decomposition = seasonal_decompose(ts_log.price.values, freq=30)`

**Edit** as to comments. Adding just `freq=30` is enough!

Comment: I had a similar error, but based on the error message, I guess adding the freq parameter did the trick.

Comment: you fixed it not by adding by `values`, instead by adding `freq=30`

Comment: What is "freq" doing here, exactly?

Comment: I doubt this is correct. [Docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose.html) has no `freq` param, I think either you change the `freq` param of the datetime (as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61593097/5931672) answer) or you use the `period` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this error by:

```
ts_log = ts_log.asfreq('d')
```

this may generate some missing values:

```
ts_log = ts_log.fillna(method='bfill').fillna(method='ffill')
```

Answer (score 0):

Following has resolved the error :

```
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(log_county_data , period = 30)
```